# map does not update with respect to base_link

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, update, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,
can someone tell me why the map is not updating with respect to the displacement in base_link? The map keeps building at one place, whereas I can see the laser data moving wrt base_link, but the map doesn't move.

1. launched the laser scan
2. static tf between map and odom(slam is supposed to provide this, but I always get map frame not available)

3)Odom publisher

4)static tf between base_link and camera_link

5)then I launch the slam_gmapping.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1b4HVWzpKfWp937sdIS8cLRbGr5eIMtLh?usp=sharing

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362240/map-does-not-update-with-respect-to-base_link/) by [Gourav](https://answers.ros.org/users/59487/gourav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-09-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-09-24**:
Can you please add the pdf output of `rosrun tf view_frames` to that folder?

**Comment by [Gourav](https://answers.ros.org/users/59487/gourav/) on 2020-09-24**:
done.. I included that

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-09-24**:
Thanks for doing that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A big red flag is that your `map->odom` transform is static. That is almost certainly the reason for the problem behavior. `slam_gmapping` is responsible for producing that. For some reason I don't understand, you said that you override the `map->odom` tf with a static transfrom publisher. Remove that and let gmapping publish the `map->odom` tf and then we should be on our way to fixing the problem.

---

Originally posted by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) with karma: 977 on 2020-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gourav](https://answers.ros.org/users/59487/gourav/) on 2020-09-24**:
I agree with you, but I keep getting this error (https://answers.ros.org/question/361629/unable-to-create-map-using-gmapping-ros-melodic-on-jetson-nano/) if I don't do the map->odom static transform... I will try once more and will update.
thanks for the reply :-)

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-09-24**:
Add a copy of `rosrun tf view_frames` pdf output without the static `map->odom` publisher please. Make sure gmapping is running.

**Comment by [Gourav](https://answers.ros.org/users/59487/gourav/) on 2020-09-24**:
Updated the file again.

**Comment by [Gourav](https://answers.ros.org/users/59487/gourav/) on 2020-09-24**:
its the same problem, btw I used the following files https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-09-24**:
And when you `rostopic echo /your/laser/scan/topic` what is the frame_id in the header?

**Comment by [Gourav](https://answers.ros.org/users/59487/gourav/) on 2020-09-24**:
camera_depth_frame

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-09-24**:
And is this all in simulation on the same computer?

**Comment by [Gourav](https://answers.ros.org/users/59487/gourav/) on 2020-09-24**:
yes it is.

**Comment by [Gourav](https://answers.ros.org/users/59487/gourav/) on 2020-09-24**:
don't understand why the slam is not providing the transform between map and doom..

**Comment by [Gourav](https://answers.ros.org/users/59487/gourav/) on 2020-09-24**:
The only changes I made in this file (https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping) is ..
   ----to----     
and changed the maxRange ..